# Theoretical physics stack exchange site

Tags: discussion

This isn't really a question as such, but rather an add for another stackexchange proposal which is likely of interest to at least a few of the users here. I know this is off topic, even for meta, so I'll understand if this gets closed/deleted. I only take the liberty of posting this following a suggesting from one of the mods.

At the moment, there is a [Theoretical Physics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23848/theoretical-physics?referrer=6MFJJ0ze0OFN-CahX8P22A2) on Area 51, which is at 77% commitment. There are already enough low rep users, but in order to progress to beta we still need more users with over 200 rep. Although there is currently a Physics.SE it is at a pretty basic level (think math.se rather than MathOverflow), and so the current proposal is for a physics site made in the image of this site (TCS.SE) which would be explicitly research level only.

TCS.SE currently has quite a lot of quantum info people for whom the new site may hold some interest. It might also be of interest from the perspective of statistical mechanics, which is showing up more and more in TCS.

In any case, if this proposal sounds of interest to you, I hope you'll consider committing so that we can progress to beta soon and make the site a reality.

Comment: I committed way back :).

Comment: I posted about this on my blog just now.

Comment: @Suresh: Actually what's currently letting us down is our "commitment score" which is adversely affected by the age of some of the commitments. If you could uncommit, and the recommit it would give us a bump. We're at 100% and 98% on the other two metrics.

Comment: By the way, thanks everyone for your help. We jumped 10% in the last 12 hours.

Comment: @Joe, another meta site that you may want to consider for advertising is [meta.stats.SE](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/), there are probably some statistical physics researchers around there that might be interested in the proposal.

Comment: @Kaveh: Thanks, I will try there.

Comment: hah ! I did as Joe suggested, and got the score up to 89% :)

Comment: Thanks @Suresh!

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks everyone. We hit 100% last week, and I believe the beta will be starting this week.

Comment: that's excellent. looking forward to it.

Comment: The beta seems to have started, but the link in the email inviting me to participate doesn't seem to work. I'll look at it in a week.

Comment: @Peter: You can just go to http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com In any case, it's great to have you on board!

Answer (score 3):

Another potential way of advertising, is to write a cstheory blogpost about your question:

[Physics results in TCS?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2074/1037)

and include a plug for phtheory at the end. If you wet the csers appetite with a little physics used in TCS then they might be more tempted to learn more at phtheory.